# Proof of probability ratio monotonicity

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Imagine, there are two possible states, A or B. There are N people who have beliefs about which state is the true one. You are one of them. You know your own belief only, which is p=Prob(A is true state). You also know that the beliefs of the others are distributed according to $F_X(p)$, $X\in\{A,B\}$, depending on whether the true state is A or B.

Then, you are let to observe how many other people are "around" you in terms of their beliefs, i.e. how many people have beliefs in the range $[p-\delta, p+\delta]$, where $p$ is your belief, and $\delta$ is set such that you expect to observe exactly 1 other person in your range. I.e.

$n \left( p(F_A(p+\delta)-F_A(p-\delta)) +(1-p)(F_B(p+\delta)-F_B(p-\delta))   \right)=1$.

My goal is to show that the ratio of state conditional probabilities to observe 0 in your range $\frac{P(0|B)}{P(0|A)}=\left(\frac{1-F_B(p+\delta)-F_B(p-\delta)}{1-F_A(p+\delta)-F_A(p-\delta)}\right)^{N-1}$ is decreasing in $p$.

Two things are given. 1) Distributions are symmetric in a sense that $f_A(x)=f_B(1-x)$, $F_A(x)=1-F_B(1-x)$ and 2) Monotone likelihood ratio property holds, i.e. $\frac{f_A(x)}{f_B(x)}$ is increasing for all $x$.

I would very much appreciate if somebody could help me to answer the following questions:

1) Is it actually true that the ratio I am interested in is decreasing? Intuitively it should be the case, and I haven't found a counterexample so far.

2) If so, any hint how to show this formally?

3) If not, what are the least restrictive assumptions to make it true? Anything less than monotonic pdfs?

Comment: I don't get the belief part. Why it is a probability? Am I unsure about my own belief?

Comment: There is true underlying state, A or B, but you don't know which one. You believe that the true state is A with probability p. Others may have different beliefs; you know they are distributed according to $F_A$ if the true state is A and according to $F_B$ if B.

Comment: The measure of belief is confidence, or certainty.